# xslt sort list and assign a unique number

Tags: xslt, sorting, numbers, unique, assign

XSLT Sorting and assign an unique number to each group: I want to sort and assign a unique number for each group after the sorting. sort based on `<Type>` & `<Location>` using xslt. Please see below for the input and output expected.

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:Payload xmlns:ns1="http://abcd.ef.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>141414</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>151515</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1215</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>313131</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>MM</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>112233</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>112334</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
    </ns1:Detail>
</ns1:Payload>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:Payload xmlns:ns1="http://abcd.ef.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>112233</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>1</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>112334</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>1</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>313131</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>2</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>2</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>MM</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>3</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>141414</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>4</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:Detail>
        <ns1:ID>151515</ns1:ID>
        <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
        <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
        <ns1:MsgGroup>4</ns1:MsgGroup>
    </ns1:Detail>
</ns1:Payload>
```

Comment: You want `<Type>` sorted in the order `SS`...`MM`...`MT`? That's not consistent.  You may have meant to sort by `<Location>` first, then `<Type>`.

Comment: Please check your output. There are items there that do not exist in the input XML.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? You really need to tell us, since half the community is using the old version and half the new, and the solutions are likely to be radically different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at this even though there are inconsistencies between your input XML and expected output. :) You can tell me if what I produce is incorrect.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ns1="http://abcd.ef.com" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:key
    name="kDetail"
    match="ns1:Detail"
    use="concat(ns1:Type, '+', ns1:Location)" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="ns1:Detail[
          generate-id() = 
          generate-id(
            key('
              kDetail',
              concat(ns1:Type, '+', ns1:Location)
            )[1]
          )
        ]">    
        <xsl:sort select="ns1:Location" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Detail">
    <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('kDetail', concat(ns1:Type, '+', ns1:Location))">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <ns1:MsgGroup>
          <xsl:value-of select="$vPos" />
        </ns1:MsgGroup>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is run against the provided XML (corrected, *I think*, to eliminate inconsistencies):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:Payload
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ns1="http://abcd.ef.com">
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>141414</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>151515</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>313131</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MM</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>112233</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>112334</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
  </ns1:Detail>
</ns1:Payload>
```

**...the wanted result is (I think) produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns1:Payload
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ns1="http://abcd.ef.com">
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>112233</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>1</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>112334</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1211</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>1</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>313131</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>2</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>SS</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>2</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>123123</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MM</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1213</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>3</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>141414</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>4</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
  <ns1:Detail>
    <ns1:ID>151515</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Type>MT</ns1:Type>
    <ns1:Location>1214</ns1:Location>
    <ns1:MsgGroup>4</ns1:MsgGroup>
  </ns1:Detail>
</ns1:Payload>
```